# Laravel Authentication: The 'guest' method of the default web guard redirects other logged in guards

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I have a custom guard named 'customers'.

**Config/Auth.php**

```
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'customers' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'customers',
        ],
    ],
```

The login page of the default guard has a method to redirect the already logged in users of the that guard.

**LoginController.php**

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
}
```

But this redirects the logged in users of other guards too.

I have tried modifying the abouve method

```
public function __construct()
{
        $this->middleware('guest:web')->except('logout');
}
```

But no results.

My customer model

```
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use App\Notifications\CustomerResetPasswordNotification;

class Customer extends Authenticatable
{
   use SoftDeletes;
   use Notifiable;

   protected $guard = 'customers';
   use \Askedio\SoftCascade\Traits\SoftCascadeTrait;

   protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
   protected $guarded = ['id'];
   protected $softCascade = ['address'];
   protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];

   public function address()
   {

    return $this->hasMany(AddressBook::class);

   }

    public function ipaddress()
    {

      return $this->hasMany(IpAddress::class);
    }

    public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
    {
        $this->notify(new CustomerResetPasswordNotification($token));
    }

    public function coupons()
    {
      return  $this->belongsToMany(Coupon::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your Customer model

Comment: Yes.I've added it now

Comment: can you show your middle were

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth:customer')->except('logout');
}
```